# CvMLData::get_responses() in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to use [CvMLData::get_responses](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/mldata.html#cvmldata-get-responses) but it does not give me the responses.

I got as many rows as samples as the documentation says but instead of the responses I got the first n values, where n is equivalent to the rows or samples.

This is my example (the firs column is the response):

```
1,0,9
1,5,4
2,7,7
1,5,5
2,9,9
```

Here is my code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/ml.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CvMLData cvml;
    cvml.read_csv("examples.csv");
    // Indicate the column that has the response
    cvml.set_response_idx(0); 
    const CvMat* rs = cvml.get_responses();
    cout << "Rows: " << rs->rows << " Cols: " << rs->cols << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < rs->rows; i++ ) {
        cout << rs->data.fl[i] << "\n"; 
    } 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And this is the output I get.

```
Rows: 5 Cols: 1
1
0
9
1
5
```

As you can see, I am just getting the initial 5 values. I am using OpenCV 2.3 and this is part of a bigger problem I am trying to solve.

This is probably more a bug than a question, but still I could be doing something wrong or misunderstanding something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built my own answeer. It is more a workaround but anyway. It is working. I am using the CVMLData::get_values() method and calculating the next first column.

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CvMLData cvml;
    cvml.read_csv("examples.csv");
    cvml.set_response_idx(0);
    const CvMat* vs = cvml.get_values();
    cout << "Rows: " << vs->rows << " Cols: " << vs->cols << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < vs->rows; i++ )
    {
        cout << vs->data.fl[i*vs->cols] << "\n"; 
    } 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the result:

Notice that I am multiplying i * vs->cols so I just get the first column.

```
Rows: 5 Cols: 3
1
1
2
1
2
```

This code works just if the response is in the first column. If not add the column number, like this

```
cout << vs->data.fl[i*vs->cols + YOUR_COLUMN_RESPONSE] << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CvMLData cvml;
    cvml.read_csv("examples.csv");
    cvml.set_response_idx(0);
    const CvMat* vs = cvml.get_values();
    cout << "Rows: " << vs->rows << " Cols: " << vs->cols << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < vs->rows; i++ ) {
        for(int j = 0; j < vs->cols; j++ ) {
          cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*vs, float, i, j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return CvMat is a Matrix, so has to access following below code, although it's just one column.

```
const CvMat* rs = cvml.get_responses();
cout << "Rows: " << rs->rows << " Cols: " << rs->cols << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < rs->rows; i++ ) {
    for(int j = 0; j < rs->cols; j++ ) {
      cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*rs, float, i, j) << endl; // 应该这样获取
    }
}
```